# Write Sql script to fetch data in one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to write a sql script which fetches data from 2 tables one is parent and second is child table

Bid

### BidId | Code | Date

1     |  H   |  2022-05-12
2     |  B   |  2022-05-13

BidResult

### BidResultId | BidId    | Emi

12          |     1    |     50

13          |     1    |     20

14          |     2    |     30

Bid and BidResult

i want fetch column Date,Code,BidId from Bid Table
and BidResultId, EMI from BidResult but want a another column of Minimum EMI

from above example i want to fetch for bidId 1

Code H,date 2022-05-12,BidResultId 12, Emi 50 and Min Emi between 50 and 20 which is 20

so i have written following query

```
Select B.BidId,BR.EMI As Installment,
(Select Min(BR.EMI ) from BidResult BR
Inner Join Bid B on B.BidId = BR.BidResultId
where B.BidId = 5) As MinInstallment,
B.Code,
BR.BidResultId,
CONVERT(DATE, B.Date) As BidDate
from Bid B
Inner Join BidResult BR On B.BidId = BR.BidId
where B.BidId= 5 and B.TypeId = 1
```

All Field are starightforward except the minimum EMI value from BidResult for that BidId

please check the query and suggest if any modifications

Comment: This is a little hard to follow.  I think you might have better luck using a derived table, instead of a "inline" column.     I'll TRY to get you started:       Select B.BidId,BR.EMI As Installment,
B.Code,
BR.BidResultId,
CONVERT(DATE, B.Date) As BidDate



from Bid B

JOIN
(Select Min(BR.EMI) as MyMinEmi , BR.BidResultId MyBidResultId from BidResult BR
GROUP BY BR.BidResultId) 
as derived1

ON  B.BidId = derived1.MyBidResultId



Inner Join BidResult BR On B.BidId = BR.BidId
where B.BidId= 5 and B.TypeId = 1

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1: With group by

```
select BID, min(EMI) EMI
into #temp
from BIDResult
group by BID

select b.Date, b.Code, b.BidId, br.BidResultId, br.EMI 
from BID b
inner join #temp on t.BID = b.BID
inner join BIDResult br on br.BID = t.BID and br.EMI = t.EMI
```

#### Solution 2: Without group by

```
select *, ROW_Number() over(PARTITION by BID order by EMI) RowNumber
into #temp
from BIDResult

select b.Date, b.Code, b.BidId, br.BidResultId, br.EMI  
from BID b
inner join #temp t on t.BID = b.BID and t.RowNumber = 1
```